# “#1060 - Duplicate column name” converting from SELECT to UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-update

I've built out this SELECT query and it returns the correct results:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', n.contact_first_name, n.contact_last_name), n.contact_id, s.contact_id
  FROM contact n
  JOIN demographics s ON s.contact_id = n.contact_id
```

I get a table with the two names concatenated and the matching `contact_id`. My purpose with this is to write all the `contact_first_name` and `contact_last_name` into the `demographics` table under the column name `demographics_name`. However, I've tried to 'convert' my SELECT statement into an UPDATE and I ran into a duplicate column name issue. Here's the query I've tried to build:

```
UPDATE demographics d
    INNER JOIN (SELECT n.contact_first_name, n.contact_last_name, n.contact_id, s.contact_id
          FROM contact n
          JOIN demographics s ON s.contact_id = n.contact_id
    ) c 
    ON c.contact_id = d.contact_id
    SET d.demographics_name = CONCAT_WS(' ', c.contact_first_name, c.contact_last_name)
```

I can't spot the mistake I've made and I could really use the help of a fresh set of critical eyes to point out what I'm missing here.

Comment: May be I have not the freshest eyes at this time, but it seems to me that n.contact_id, s.contact_id in the INNER JOIN (SELECT... statement are not in use later. For the relationship ON s.contact_id = n.contact_id you don't need them.

Comment: Sorry, just wipe one of them: s.contact_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this just work?

```
UPDATE demographics d
    INNER JOIN contact c
    ON c.contact_id = d.contact_id
    SET d.demographics_name = CONCAT_WS(' ', c.contact_first_name, c.contact_last_name)
```

Comment: Good deal. Glad to help.